# Rails + Rspec: Patterns and Styles for it/describe/context descriptions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I know this isn't really related to the actual code itself, but I'm just starting off with Rspec and am having trouble making the tests sound like English. I think it would improve the quality of my tests a lot if I understood what to put in the strings I pass to the it and describe blocks. Ex:

```
    Category
      validations
        is valid with a title and description
        is invalid without a title
        is invalid without a description
      when it has subcategories
        returns the right children subcategories
        should be accessible by its subcategories
      when it has no subcategories
        returns an empty set
```

This is what's coming out of my Category specs. Is there a certain way/pattern I have to write the strings that I pass to `it` and `describe`? For you Rspec experts, what do you usually think of when you're writing the `describe` string, and how does that differ from when you're writing the `it` string or `context` string? Below is an example of my specs in case you need some actual code to work with:

```
  describe 'validations' do
    let(:category) { Category.new }
    it 'is valid with a title and description' do
      category.title = 'Category'
      category.description = 'Lorem Ipsum'
      category.should be_valid
    end

    it 'is invalid without a title' do
      category.description = 'Lorem Ipsum'
      category.should_not be_valid
    end

    it 'is invalid without a description' do
      category.title = 'Category'
      category.should_not be_valid
    end

  end

  context 'when it has subcategories' do
    let(:category) { FactoryGirl.create(:category) }
    it 'returns the right children subcategories' do
      child = category.subcategories.build(title: 'Child Category', description: 'Lorem Ipsum')
      category.subcategories.should include(child)
    end

    it 'should be accessible by its subcategories' do
      child = category.subcategories.build(title: 'Child Category', description: 'Lorem Ipsum')
      child.parent_category.should_not be_nil
    end
  end

  context 'when it has no subcategories' do
    let(:category) { FactoryGirl.create(:category) }
    it 'returns an empty set' do
      category.subcategories.should be_empty
    end
  end
```

Comment: It's actually quite nice in my opinion. So I guess there is no question? One minor thing is you can change first `describe` to `context` to match the siblings.

Comment: Thanks. I was a bit lost though, and I'm sure many people are so it's still helpful to me and others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically:

- `describe` is for "something". "Something" can be a instance or class method, or an action in features specs. ".method_name" if it is a class method  and "#method_name" if it is a instance method.
- `context`  is for describe a special case of spec (context is an alias for `describe`). Usually start with "when".
- `it` is what does 'something'. Usually start with "should".

---

```
describe ".to_s"
  context "when is a number"
    it "convert the number in a string"
  context "when is a string"
    it "return the same object"
```

But this is not strictly. Here's a guidance:

- https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/basic-structure-describe-it
- http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/an-introduction-to-rspec
- http://eggsonbread.com/2010/03/28/my-rspec-best-practices-and-tips/

Answer (score 0):

I generally begin my test case with `should`. So your test run will have something like

```
Category
      validations
        should be valid with a title and description
        should be invalid without a title
        should be invalid without a description
      with subcategories
        should return the right children subcategories
        should be accessible by its subcategories
      without subcategories
        should return an empty set
```

I find it easier to understand the functionality when it is like above.